# Struct Arrays - elements being overwritten

Tags: arrays, c, struct

First off - I am very rusty at C ... but have a project that needs my rusty skills nonetheless ... apologies for the "crude" way in which I may have perhaps coded my solution.

My basic requirement is to simply populate a fixed strut array with elements to be later read and processed. This array is intended to be "global" and used from a few .C files in the solution.

The issue I am having is that while some elements are added just fine, there are some that get "overwritten" by other elements - making the array inaccurate as it does not contain all the needed populated elements.

The struct is defined as such in the header file :-

```
typedef struct {
char* field;
char* value;} Telemetry;
```

The array is initialized as such :-

```
Telemetry* myArray[5];
```

To Add to the Array I have a function that checks for the next empty "slot" :-

```
int addToArray(Telemetry* telemetry)
{
   counter = 0;

  //Determine next available element
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {

      if (myArray[i] == NULL)
      {
          break;
      }
      else
      {
        Counter++;
      }


      myArray[counter] = telemetry;
  }
}
```

Then to add elements the application receives data from a CANBUS system - and each value is interpreted  :-

```
    //Define Struct Values

//Dialectric
    char* dialectricvalueBuffer = (char*)malloc(30);
    sprintf(dialectricvalueBuffer, "%f", 50.3);

    Telemetry dialectricTelemetry = { .field = "DialectricConst", .value = dialectricvalueBuffer };

//Density
    char* densityvalueBuffer = (char*)malloc(30);
    sprintf(densityvalueBuffer, "%f", 9);

    Telemetry densityTelemetry = { .field = "Density", .value = densityvalueBuffer };

    //Viscosity
    char* viscosityvalueBuffer = (char*)malloc(30);
    sprintf(viscosityvalueBuffer, "%f", 21.9);

    Telemetry viscosityTelemetry = { .field = "Viscosity", .value = viscosityvalueBuffer};

    
    //Add values to array
    addToArray(&densityTelemetry);
    addToArray(&viscosityTelemetry);
    addToArray(&dialectricTelemetry);
```

At this point elements 0,1,2 of myArray are populated just fine.

Then a separate process (that reads Temperature) executes the same function to add elements to the array as such :-

```
char* tempvalueBuffer = (char*)malloc(30);
sprintf(tempvalueBuffer, "%f", temperature);


Telemetry tempTelemetry = { .field = "Temperature", .value = tempvalueBuffer };

//Add values to array
addTelemetryToQueue(&tempTelemetry);
```

And every single time - Element 2 (DialectricConst) gets replaced with the Temperature element.

No matter where I move the DialectricConst element in the array - it always gets replaced by the temperature data as soon as

```
Telemetry tempTelemetry = { .field = "Temperature", .value = tempvalueBuffer };
```

executes.

Any explanation as to why - would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you take any measures to prevent your second process from accessing the array at the same time? As you add pointers to local variables, are you sure you did not return from that function where the elements are added to the array? Did you step through `addToArray` in a debugger? I would assume it does not what you think it does.

Comment: I would suggest to use `malloc` to allocate memory for `dialectricTelemetry` instead of using a local variable. Same for all the other variables you add to the array.

Comment: *"Then a separate process..."* - I assume you mean a separate *function*. You just loaded up your array with addresses of structures have expire the moment the function calling `addToArray` three times returns. Those addresses are now dangling, and any dereference to them invokes *undefined behavior*. I've yet to see any evidence whatsoever why `myArray` isn't just five instances, not five pointers. All you're doing is increasing complexity for literally no win and management headache. The same could be said for the `field` member as well, though the `value` member is arguably understandable.

Comment: Is this actually code you use or some completely unrelated stuff you just made up for this question? You need to have a very fault tolerant compiler to digest this.

Comment: Thanks for the questions! 
Yes this was an "extract" of copying at pasting to illustrate the issue - mainly just to hone in where I see the problem.

Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: Next time please really copy your code. The code you show does not even compile. Please read what a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is which is expected from you and add one for future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few details you do not show and I have to fill in some assumptions:

**assumptions...**

You have a function that receives from CANbus and some other function that measures temperature.
You mention that these are in different processes, but I assume you actually meant different threads or just other functions. Otherwise they would not be able to share the same array without some extra effort.

Within both functions you have local variables allocated on the stack. Then you add these to your array where you only store the address of the variables in the array but you do not allocate extra memory.
That means that after leaving these 2 functions, the local variables are not longer valid. Accessing them via the pointers in your array is causing undefined behaviour.

**assumptions end**

On the other side, you do show the function to add the elements.
In that function you have a severe flaws:

```c
int addToArray(Telemetry* telemetry)
{
   counter = 0;

  //Determine next available element
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {

      if (myArray[i] == NULL)
      {
          break;
      }
      else
      {
        Counter++;
      }
      myArray[counter] = telemetry;
  }
}
```

If there are a few elements that already hold an address, you store the new address in every successor
If `myArray[0] != NULL` you execute `counter++;` and then `myArray[counter] = telemetry;` which fills `myArray[1]` with a valid address and in the next iteration of you loop you will do the same again until all elements are filled with same value.

On the other side, if you hit an entry that is still `NULL`, you break from your loop and do not assign anything at all.

Which in turn leads to the conclusion that your claim "At this point elements 0,1,2 of myArray are populated just fine." is far from being true.

Finally, you do not return a value while you promised to return an `int`. Not to mention that you do not define a type for `counter` and have case mismatch with `Counter`.

Then you have more undefined behaviour in your calling function:

```c
sprintf(densityvalueBuffer, "%f", 9);
```

This passes an `int` value while you promised to pass a `double` value.

Your compiler should show quite some warnings when confronted with that code.

A fixed version would be:

```c
int addToArray(Telemetry* telemetry)
{
  Telemetry *new_elem = malloc(sizeof(*new_elem));
  if (new_elem == NULL)
  {
      return -1;
  }

  *new_elem = *telemetry;

  //Determine next available element
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
      if (myArray[i] == NULL)
      {
          myArray[i] = new_elem;
          break;
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This version creates a copy of the passed variable.
It also stores the pointer in the first available element.

Comment: Thank you Gerhardh! 

These two lines resolved the issue!

  Telemetry *new_elem = malloc(sizeof(*new_elem));
  *new_elem = *telemetry;

I was not assigning the values to a new variable - then adding the newly created variable to the array.

Thanks again for the detailed explanation! - Really appreciated!

Comment: Your loop to find the next available element also was completely wrong. These 2 lines are not sufficient.

Comment: Correct- that was corrected too.
Thanks